# IllegalArgumentException when using QuerydslBinderCustomizer with Kotlin Spring Data

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I've been using Spring Data's querydsl support in order to do filtering on my domain entities. 
However, when I try to override the customize method of QuerydslBinderCustomizer in my repository, I get an IllegalArgumentException as follows:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.my.project.repository.TripRepository.customize(org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBindings,com.my.project.domain.trip.QTrip)! No property customize found for type Trip!

My repository is defined as follows:

```
@Repository
interface TripRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Trip, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Trip>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QTrip> {
    fun findByState(tripState: TripState): List<Trip>

    override fun customize(bindings: QuerydslBindings, root: QTrip) {
        bindings.excluding(root.anonymousToken)
    }
}
```

It seems like PagingAndSortingRepository is searching for a customize field on my Trip entity, despite it being a method override from another interface. I've tried adding an empty @Query annotation to the customize method hoping that it would be ignored to no avail.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

#### Update

I haven't managed to get this working in Kotlin. I ended up (begrudgingly) converting my repository classes to Java, which solved the problem.

#### Update

The solution for this issue is to use the @JvmDefault annotation on the customize method.

```
@Repository
interface TripRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Trip, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Trip>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QTrip> {
    fun findByState(tripState: TripState): List<Trip>

    @JvmDefault
    override fun customize(bindings: QuerydslBindings, root: QTrip) {
        bindings.excluding(root.anonymousToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: using kotlin, spring-data-rest with querydslproduced

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property customize found for type <MyEntity>
```

To overcome this, I specified

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjvm-default=all"]
    }
}
```

in my `build.gradle` to make kotlin use the JVM version of interface default methods.

That fixed that problem!